# Static IP configuration causing apt-get errors

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, apt

I am getting errors when running `apt-get update` or when installing new packages.  Although this only happens when the server configured for a static IP address.  Changing the configuration back to DHCP and restarting networking fixes the problem, although I want a static IP. Once it is working I can change back to my static IP address and restart networking. Although this only works until I restart the server (restarting the router is ok), and then I start getting the same errors and have to switch back to DHCP.

Any ideas on what could be causing this or tips on troubleshooting it? Thanks in advance.

- here is my static IP configuration:

  ```
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.2.2
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.2.1
  ```
- The `apt-get update` errors go something like this:

  A few of these

  ```
  Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease
  ```

  then a lot of these

  ```
  Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg   Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
  ```

  and a lot of these

  ```
  W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
  ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't able to resolve domains via DNS. Assuming this is the case, you can likely fix it by **adding a `dns-nameservers` line  to `/etc/network/interfaces`**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.2.1
```

**and then running**

```
resolvconf -u
```

**as root to update `/etc/resolv.conf`**. Feel free to include a DNS search domain record (which is also typically handed out via DHCP). Refer to [resolvconf(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/resolvconf.8.html) for more information.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting to you may need to restart your network after changing `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```